# General Protection Fault error on Centos 6 while executing a python script

Tags: centos, python, linux, centos6

I have a python(fabric) script running on a centos 6 box that parses configuration files and daemonizes MRTG process and dumps rrd files a folder in a shared file system. All goes well but midway to the process I get the error [image attached below].

Command issued , `fab -f /path/to/my/fabfile.py $functionName`

It parses around 260 configuration files and dumps the rrds for the same. I am out of ideas as what might have caused this and am still searching for solutions. I disabled ksm/ksmtuned (just a hit) but that did not solve it.

[image: Error]

**UPDATE**

I installed same OS with same kernel, same scripts and same python version, everything identical ... on a different server, which is comparatively newer than the one earlier, and so far haven't experienced any issues, its been a couple of hours now. So it puts out the server/software being a reason for the error so far, probably its the hardware!! Will try upgrading the BIOS on the older one as a few links online suggested having similar issues with older version of BIOS when running disk-intensive processes. Would update my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems one of the memory module installed was the issue. Changing it seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In future when you have weird core dumps or GPF's , always take the server down and run a memtest from the grub menu.

Comment: tks :) will take that in account.